# How do I completely reset a laptop, changing the main drive in the process?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, operating-systems, reset

I have a used laptop, and I wanting to do a factory reset, but also change the main drive.

The main drive right now is C:, with 256GB, and the one I want to switch to is D: with 1TB.

How do I reset the computer and change the drive windows is on (wipe both drives)?

[The drives. Both are internal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZDMF.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to just download windows onto USB drive (or DVD) which you then use to install windows. Put in your new 1TB drive then boot of win-install USB drive. You can delete everything on new drive during the install. Almost all windows 10 installs electronically store the windows product key/license so it should just license itself with no issue. If it does have issue you can just reinstall old drive to get back to your old setup.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10%20

If desired you could reset the PC on the current drive, but I feel like that's a waste of time & doesn't actually delete files, free programs can recover deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing or changing the hard drive is enough for a "factory reset", meaning you have no more any personal data on it.
I understand you want to use a 1TB drive instead of the existing 0.25TB.

Clearing the question about drive letters: As probably your laptop can handle only one internal hard drive at a time, there will be only the new 1TB disk installed.
Upon its installation, Windows will assign drive letters depending on existing partitions and your choices during the new installation process.

So, of course you have to change the drive first following the process described of the manufacturer (get and see the right manual first).
Once this done, you will need a way to boot your laptop into an OS that includes or has access to the new Windows installation files (if the 1TB drive is a new one, of course you don't need erasing anything on it, otherwise you will need as well a tool to do so).

If you see now a D: pointing to your new disk, as you described, would mean that you managed to connect it through some USB/SATA adaptor. If so, you can reverse them and use the first (old) one to boot and install your new OS.

Otherwise, the easiest way to boot an "empty" system, is by USB flash drive, external (USB) hard disk, or a physical CD/DVD. Each of them needs to be prepared first (on a working PC).
How to make external storage devices bootable is an other question, but if needed you can look here: https://easy2boot.xyz/
You can use a tool downloaded from the above site, to make a bootable USB flash drive, that basically extracts the Windows installation ISO to it.
There would be another way by installing Grub4dos on it (for ex. with Bootice, https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice_64_bit.html) along with the installation ISO and than "chainloading" it. It's quite easy.

If you need to secure erase, you can use for ex. ShredOS : https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.x86_64 or pick another one from here: https://www.geckoandfly.com/24060/secure-wipe-clean-ssd/-+

Your question is a little wide, but here are some ideas, as my first post here. :-)

Answer (score -2):

format both drives.
place the larger one in the main spot and turn on the laptop so it writes boot sector.

install Win from USB or whatever method you choose.
use disk management to designate the second smaller drive as storage

alternately you could simply do a full reset of windows on the original drive then clone it to the larger drive and just swap their places

you will however need to start the machine once with the larger drive in first port ,to get that boot sector created as most cloning software doesn't carry it over, before cloning it.... which means put it in. start. remove, put smaller back in. connect 2nd either in chassis or by usb sata ..clone. then put 2 larger drive (now cloned) in to primary spot

but like others say.... the easiest way will be to put the larger drive in and install win fresh